# no such table error when running knex seed test data

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, backend, knex.js

I am having an issue when trying to `knex seed:run` with my test data.

I'm getting an error saying that there is no such table even if the table is there and can be opened in *sqlitestudio*..

Below, the code from the `knexfile`, `cleanup`, and  `migration` file.

I apologize in advance if my post format is wrong, this is my first time posting here.

Thanks in advance !

#### Error message :

```
    $ knex seed:run
Using environment: development
Error: Error while executing "C:\Users\jessb\Desktop\School\Assignments\Web-API-Node\Adding-Data-Persistence\node-db4-project\data\seeds\00-cleanup.js" seed: delete from `recipe_ingredients` - SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: main.undefined
    at Seeder._waterfallBatch (C:\Users\jessb\Desktop\School\Assignments\Web-API-Node\Adding-Data-Persistence\node-db4-project\node_modules\knex\lib\seed\Seeder.js:118:23)
Error: delete from `recipe_ingredients` - SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: main.undefined
```

#### migration file :

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema
    .createTable("recipe", (tbl) => {
      tbl.increments();
      tbl.string("recipe_name", 128).notNullable();
    })
    .createTable("ingredient", (tbl) => {
      tbl.increments();
      tbl.string("ingredient_name", 128).notNullable();
    })
    .createTable("instructions", (tbl) => {
      tbl.increments();
      tbl.string("instruction").notNullable();
      tbl.integer("recipe_id").unsigned().notNullable().references("recipe.id");
      tbl.integer("recipe_step").notNullable();
    })
    .createTable("recipe_ingredients", (tbl) => {
      tbl.increments();
      tbl.string("ingredient_quantity").notNullable();
      tbl.integer("recipe_id").unsigned().notNullable().references("recipe.id");
      tbl
        .integer("ingredient_id")
        .unsigned()
        .notNullable()
        .references("ingredient_id");
    });
};

exports.down = function (knex) {
    return knex.schema
        .dropTableIfExists('recipe_ingredients')
        .dropTableIfExists('instruction')
        .dropTableIfExists('ingredient')
        .dropTableIfExists('recipe')
};
```

#### knexfile.js :

```
module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    useNullAsDefault: true,
    connection: {
      filename: './data/recipes.db3'
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: './data/migrations'
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: './data/seeds'
    },
    pool: {
      afterCreate: (conn, done) => {
        // runs after a connection is made to the sqlite engine
        conn.run('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON', done); // turn on FK enforcement
      },
  },
},

  staging: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'my_db',
      user:     'username',
      password: 'password'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'my_db',
      user:     'username',
      password: 'password'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  }
```

#### Cleanup :

```
const cleaner = require('knex-cleaner');

exports.seed = function(knex) {
  return cleaner.clean(knex, {
    mode: 'truncate', // resets ids
    ignoreTables: ['knex_migrations', 'knex_migrations_lock'], // don't empty migration tables
  });
};
```